# error in string copy using character pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I was implementing string copy function using character pointers but it is showing error. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *s="abc";
    char *t;
    while((*s)!='\0')
    {
        *t++=*s++;
    }
    *t='\0';
    printf("%s\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It is showing error"-**What** is the error?

Answer (score 7):

```
char *t;
```

There is no memory allocated to your pointer and you are trying to write to it which will lead to undefined behavior.So allocate memory

```
char *t = malloc(30); /* size of your choice or strlen(s) + 1*/
```

Once done using the memory free it using

```
free(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might result in a `segmentation fault`

The reason being : **Just think where is `char *t` pointing to right now?**

Let's have a look at the possibilities :

1.Your `char *t` is pointing to some memory location which can not be accessed or write-protected;

2.It might work in some cases where your pointer is pointing to a memory location that can be accessed and has required space.The possibilities of that being very small.

So, it's better to use

```
char *t=NULL;
t=malloc(sizeof(char)*n); //Dynamic approach
```

here n is the no of bytes you are allocating to `t`

If you're not comfortable with dynamic memory allocation right now
reserve some space for `t` which you think is enough. This will waste some space though.

After you're done, free the space allocated;

```
free(t);
```

**Note** : Always include `<stdlib.h>` else malloc will result in a warning.

Comment: There is no need to cast the result of malloc/calloc/realloc in C, nor is it recommended in any ways to do so. Do not do it.

Comment: You're right @alk. It automatically promotes the `(void *)` pointer returned by malloc to the other pointer type. However , if you want your code to work in both C and C++ you must use casting. Although in C,it is a complete waste as it increases and hides some potential risks.